# In ConTeXt, how to make leftpage/rightpage arguments of setupbackgrounds work properly?

Tags: context, backgrounds, watermark

**My goal is to set a background to my document containing both a tiled image and a watermark. The watermark must be different on odd and even pages.**

When I use `page` as `setupbackgrounds` first argument, I do have both the background image and the watermark on all pages (but of course the same watermark on all pages), i.e. everything work as I expect, but this is not the result I try to achieve.

However, if I instead use `leftpage` or `rightpage` (as a first step toward my goal to differentiate between odd and even pages), I loose both the image and the watermark on ALL pages : in other words, the layer is not applied anywhere anymore.

Here is a minimal (non)working example:

```
% Document main configuration
\setuppapersize[A4]                             % document page size
\setupbodyfont[10pt]                            % document default font size

% --- Font families definitions ---
\definefontfamily[myfont][serif][myfontname]

% --- Document Background ---
\define\mybgimg                                 % macro for background image code
    {\backgroundimage{1}                        % - 1 = tiled along x & y
        {\paperwidth}{\paperheight}             % - set width and height of the addition
        {\externalfigure[bg.jpg]}}              % - addition of a bg image

\define[1]\mywatermarkformat{{                  % macro to format the watermark
    \switchtobodyfont[myfont]                   % - set font family
    \switchtobodyfont[105pt]                    % - set font size
    \color[red]{#1}                             % - set color to text argument
}}

\definelayer[mybglayer]                         % define and name new layer for the bg
    [x=0mm, y=0mm,                              % - from upper left corner of paper
    width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight,     % - let the layer cover the full paper
    repeat=yes%                                 % - layer on all pages
]
\setlayer[mybglayer]{\mybgimg}                  % fill layer with bg image
\setlayer[mybglayer]                            % fill layer with watermark
    [hoffset=0cm, voffset=23cm]                 % - placement from layer upper left corner
    {\mywatermarkformat{foobar}}                % - watermark text

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybglayer]  % <--- OK : place the layer on all pages
% OR
\setupbackgrounds[leftpage][background=mybglayer]% <---- NOT OK : place nothing at all

% --- Document Content ---
\starttext
    \input knuth
    \page
    \input knuth
    \page
    \input knuth
    \page
    \input knuth
\stoptext
```

I'm a beginner with ConTeXt, so please do not hesitate to tell me if, independantly of the main question, you can see some dubious constructs in the code.

Comment: The background for a left page is only placed in a double sided document (`\setuppapegnumbering[alternative=doublesided]`) but your document is single sided with right pages only.

Comment: Ok, adding the correct page numbering alternative indeed solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the document to doublesided.  You should also take better care of spurious spaces.

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\definefontfamily[myfont][serif][TeX Gyre Pagella]
\setupbodyfont[myfont,105pt] % preload
\setupbodyfont[modern,10pt]

\define\mybgimg
  {\backgroundimage{1}%
    {\paperwidth}{\paperheight}%
    {\externalfigure[cow]}}

\define[1]\mywatermarkformat
  {{\switchtobodyfont[myfont,105pt]\color[red]{#1}}}

\definelayer
  [page]
  [width=\paperwidth,
   height=\paperheight,
   repeat=yes]

\definelayer[rightlayer][page]
\definelayer[leftlayer][page]

\setlayer
  [rightlayer]
  {\mybgimg}

\setlayer
  [rightlayer]
  [hoffset=0cm,voffset=23cm]
  {\mywatermarkformat{right page}}

\setlayer
  [leftlayer]
  {\mybgimg}

\setlayer
  [leftlayer]
  [hoffset=0cm,voffset=23cm]
  {\mywatermarkformat{left page}}

\setupbackgrounds[rightpage][background=rightlayer]
\setupbackgrounds[leftpage][background=leftlayer]

\starttext
\input knuth
\page
\input knuth
\page
\input knuth
\page
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]